# If $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are equal in distribution, $k=1,2$ so are $X_1/(X_1+X_2)$ and $Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, continuity

The question I have in mind is as follows

We have two sets of random variables

1) $X_k\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a_k,1)$, $k=1,2,3$.

2) $(Y_1,Y_2)\sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(a_1,a_2,a_3).$

Since the Dirichlet can be constructed using Gamma, it is known that

$$ \left( \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3},\frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2+X_3},\frac{X_3}{X_1+X_2+X_3} \right) \sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(a_1,a_2,a_3). $$

So, we have $Y_1\overset{d}{=}\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$ and $Y_2\overset{d}{=}\frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$

In this case, can we say $$\frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2}\overset{d}{=}\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}?$$

I've seen a similar reasoning in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372295/distribution-of-conditional-frequencies-when-frequencies-follow-a-dirichlet-di) in the first answer.. and wonder whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Are you supposing the $X_i$ are independent?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, they are pairwise independent

Comment: @Andeanlll : "Pairwise independent" is weaker than "independent" (despite the fact that "pairwise mutually exclusive" is stronger than "mutually exclusive"). $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if $U, V$ are random variables and $U\overset d = V$ and $g$ is a (non-random) function, then $g(U) \overset d = g(V).$ That would imply that if
$$
(Y_1,Y_2) \overset d = \left(\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}, \frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2+X_3}\right) \tag 1
$$
then
$$
\frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2} \overset d = \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}.
$$
The fact that $Y_1\overset d = \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$ and $Y_2\overset d
= \frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$ is less than what is needed, in that it omits the joint distribution of the two components, but what you asserted before that, stated above on line $(1)$, is enough.